# SIice a numpy array based on an interval?

Tags: numpy, slice, numpy-slicing, program-slicing

Is it possible to systematically slice an 1d array of length m by an interval n in numpy? Say I have a list of 1000 values, could I break that into 10 lists of 100 values easily?

Comment: Look at `np.split`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both `np.array_split()` and `np.split()` which in fact are the same with a little note (as per `np.array_split()`)

From the documentation:

```
x = np.arange(8.0)

np.array_split(x, 3)

#Result
[array([0.,  1.,  2.]), array([3.,  4.,  5.]), array([6.,  7.])]
```

> Split an array into multiple sub-arrays.
>
> Please refer to the split documentation. The only difference between
> these functions is that array_split allows indices_or_sections to be
> an integer that does not equally divide the axis. For an array of
> length l that should be split into n sections, it returns l % n
> sub-arrays of size l//n + 1 and the rest of size l//n.

Answer (score 1):

**array_split** allows one to split with unequal spacing as well, should this ever meet your needs

```
ar = np.arange(0, 20, dtype='int')

s = [2, 7, 12, 17]

np.array_split(ar, s)
Out[80]: 
[array([0, 1]),
 array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6]),
 array([ 7,  8,  9, 10, 11]),
 array([12, 13, 14, 15, 16]),
 array([17, 18, 19])]
```